# JavaScriptStringEncode in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm writing code in Javascript, and I'm looking for an analog to c#'s `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` method.

What function should I use for this when writing code in javascript?

Comment: Probably `JSON.stringify`, but it's not clear where and why you would need to do this.

Comment: I want to write a JSON serializer which accepts circular references, functions etc. That's where I'm going to use it

Comment: @ArsenZahray That's exactly what `JSON.stringify` does.

Comment: @ArsenZahray: Never say never, but AFAIK there is no ECMA-compatible way to serialize functions.

Comment: @sniffer it does not accept circular references. try JSON.stringify(window). Aslo, JSON.stringify does not escape characters like `'"`

Comment: @ArsenZahray: `JSON.stringify('foo"bar')` => `"foo\"bar"`.

Comment: ah, it works with the " character! ) ok, than it's what I need

Comment: @ArsenZahray Take a look at https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js Good starting point to deal with circular references.